# Vertical align a side by side column in MaterializeCSS

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

How do you typically vertical align "middle" the button in this example:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col s1">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="col s11 right-align">
    <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="material-icons left">add</i> Add</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zg9cjmr3/

As soon as I add `valign-wrapper` in the second inner div, it gets messed up:

https://jsfiddle.net/zg9cjmr3/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `valign-wrapper` class to the row.

```
<div class="row valign-wrapper">

  <div class="col s1">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="col s11 right-align">
    <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="material-icons left">add</i> Add</a>
  </div>

</div>
```